# Upgrade to Optaplanner 8/Drools: newKieSession returns null

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I am trying to upgrade from Optaplanner 7 to Optaplanner 8.. I use drools in my project. Since I need the method `fireAllRules` I need access to the `kieSession`. Before upgrading this was easy with placing the `kmodule.xml` in the META-INF folder and executing the following lines:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
...
...
kieSession.fireAllRules()
```

After the upgrade `kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");` returns null.

Kmodule before upgrade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="drl.eval" packages="drl.eval">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules" />
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Changed kmodule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
    <kbase name="drl.eval" packages="drl.eval">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules" />
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

I tried many things to bring it to work, but I didnt succeed. Someone any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will never work, and if you were able to do this in OP 7, you were not supposed to. KieSession is an internal detail of OptaPlanner, and you must not access it - in fact, you can break the solver if you do. We can not support your use case. (Honestly, this is the first time I see someone doing this, and I am quite surprised.)

As a side note, starting with OptaPlanner 8.23.0.Final, [score DRL support is deprecated](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2022/05/26/optaplanner-deprecates-score-drl.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 
I brought it to work by adding drools-xml-support and drools-mvel to my pom.xml.

But it looks like have to rewrite my rules anyway... :/

Comment: I didnt use KieSession during the solve process. But afterwards I fire all rules again. This rules have an augmented then-block where I save additional information to have more information about where constraint violation occurs. I dont want to have this additional things in my solve process because I thought it would slow down this process.

I solve a employee rostering problem with quite a lot of rules....

Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You can get all of your constraint justifications from the `ScoreManager`.